# Dynamically set font with React

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, google-fonts

I am making a React app that will be used by a variety of different users. Each user has the ability to set the google font that they want the app to render in and the `font-family` will be returned as part of a settings call that is made when the app initially loads. This font name is stored within the Redux store.

What I'd like to do is to request the correct font file from Google depending on what `font-family` is set by the user and then inject into the app's css for that particular font:

```
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: 'set-font', helvetica, sans-serif;
}
p, div {
  font-family: 'set-font', helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

I have done a fair bit of searching and I can't find anything about what I'm trying to achieve despite it seeming like a fairly common scenario.

I've come across [webfontloader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) which seems to be a step in the right direction for fetching the font file.

Answer (score 2):

Answer ended up being very simple.

Use the `webfontloader` library then in `componentWillReceiveProps()` check once `font-family` has been returned by settings call, then run:

```
WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: ['font-family-from-settings-call']
  }
});
```

And apply this style to app as:

```
const appStyle = {
  fontFamily: 'font-family-from-settings-call'
};
```